All locally trivial fibrations are Serre fibrations
A continuous map $p : E \to B$ is a locally trivial fibration with fiber $F$ if for all $b \in B$ there exists a neighbourhood $U \subset B$ such that $U \times F$ is homeomorphic to $p^{-1}(U)$ whose composition with $p$ is the projection to first factor $U \times F \to U$.
While $p : E \to B$ is a serre fibration if it has the homotopy lifting property with respect to all cubes $I^{n}$ for $n = 0,1,\dots$
How to prove all locally trivial fibrations are serre fibrations?
If $p : E \to B$ is a locally trivial fibration with Fiber $F$. We can decompose $B$ into smaller neighbourhoods $U_{i}$ such that there is a homeomorphism $U_{i} \times F \to p^{-1}(U_{i})$.
Let $\tilde{f} : X \to E$ and $g : X \times I \to B$ be any two maps such that $g(x,0) = p(\tilde{f}(x))$. We need to construct a map $\tilde{g} : X \times I \to E$ such that $\tilde{g}(x,0) = \tilde{f}(x)$ for all $x \in X$.
How to proceed further?

See Proposition 4.48 in Hatcher
